# Using v.distance python script parameter with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, grass-gis

This question is an extension of [Copying code generated when you put data into GUI via QGIS Plugins?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237101)

I have a Python file I want to run on two loaded layers in QGIS. The layers are TestPhotos (point) and TestObj (point). The tool I want the Python file to run is v.distance.

The column in TestObjects I use in v.distance is `OBJ_ID`

The Python file is called Test1.py. I have this code:

```
import processing

processing.runalg('grass7:v.distance', 'TestPhotos','point,line,area','TestObj','point,line,area',-1.0,-1.0,'to_attr','OBJ_ID','OBJ_ID',None,-1.0,0.0001,'nearestobj','distance')
```

I get the following output using the QGIS Python console:

```
execfile(u'C:/OSGeo4W64/Test1.py'.encode('mbcs'))
Error: Wrong parameter value: None
```

I believe it is associated with the v.distance `GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>` parameter. Any idea how to deal with this to get the Python script working?

EDIT1 - responding to comment

When I typed in `processing.alghelp('grass7:v.distance')`, i got this:

```
>>>import processing
>>>processing.alghelp('grass7:v.distance') 

    ALGORITHM: v.distance - Finds the nearest element in vector map 'to' for elements in vector map 'from'.
        from <ParameterVector>
        from_type <ParameterString>
        to <ParameterVector>
        to_type <ParameterString>
        dmax <ParameterNumber>
        dmin <ParameterNumber>
        upload <ParameterString>
        column <ParameterString>
        to_column <parameters from to>
        GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
        GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
        GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
        from_output <OutputVector>
        output <OutputVector>
```

EDIT2

When I try 'Test.py' with the following code:

```
import processing 
TestPhotos = QgsVectorLayer('c:\OSGeo4w64\TestFiles\TestPhotos.shp', 'TestPhotos', 'ogr')
TestObj = QgsVectorLayer('c:\OSGeo4w64\TestFiles\TestObj.shp', 'TestObj', 'ogr')

extent = TestPhotos.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

processing.runalg(\
'grass7:v.distance', \
TestPhotos,\
'point,line,area',\
TestObj,\
'point,line,area',\
-1.0,-1.0,\
'to_attr',\
'OBJ_ID',\
'OBJ_ID',\
"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),\
-1.0,0.0001,\
'C:\OSGeo4W64\TestFiles\Outputfile0.shp',\
'C:\OSGeo4W64\TestFiles\Outputfile1.shp')
```

The output files are correctly generated with the above code. But they are not loaded in QGIS.

Comment: what does processing.alghelp('grass7:v.distance') print out? Grass Algorithms in QGIS can change the order of certain params

Comment: Thanks Julsbreakdown. See updated question for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the error because an extent is required and it can't be set to `None`.

Before posting the code, I think there is another error linked to the input layers: they should be added as objects, and not as strings. If `'TestPhotos'` and `'TestObj'` are the names with which they are loaded in the Layers Panel, you may call them in this way (the following is a general method because I don't know if you are using the Python Console or a new script from the Processing Toolbox):

```
TestPhotos = QgsVectorLayer('path to the vector layer', 'TestPhotos', 'ogr')
TestObj = QgsVectorLayer('path to the vector layer', 'TestObj', 'ogr')
```

Then, since it seems you want to use the minimum covering extent, you may try to use the following code:

```
import processing

extent = TestPhotos.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

processing.runalg('grass7:v.distance', TestPhotos,'point,line,area',TestObj,'point,line,area',-1.0,-1.0,'to_attr','OBJ_ID','OBJ_ID',"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),-1.0,0.0001,'nearestobj','distance')
```

instead of what you have provided.

**EDIT** Perhaps, also the `'distance'` parameter could be wrong because it should be a path or `None`.

Comment: Hi mgri. I am actually using the console to call a new python file I am writing, which calls v.distance. Is that what you meant by 'new script from the Processing Toolbox'? I should clarify this in my question but just need to make sure the detail you were referring to. For the purpose of this question, assume I will be hard coding the layer name in the new python file.

Comment: I added the path to the last two parameters and it worked!! (almost fully). Can you please edit your answer to explain how to add the layers in QGIS  canvas once they're generated? At this stage, the files are just generated in the directory but not loaded in QGIS.

Comment: @Joe - You could try replacing `runalg` with `runandload`. If that doesn't work then use `runalg` and add the following at the end: `iface.addVectorLayer('C:/OSGeo4W64/TestFiles/Outputfile0.shp', 'layerName', 'ogr')`

Comment: @Joe You may follow the suggestions provided by Joseph: do they work for you?