# V.distance with Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, distance

I want to resolve this problem:

I have a layer with several points, and another layer with several lines, and I want to join each point with the closest line, for that I want to use the `v.distance` because it worked with the toolbox. But I want to do it with python, I saw [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237236/using-v-distance-python-script-parameter-with-pyqgis) question. But I tried that and didn't work.

Guess that `"layer1"` and `"layer2"` I got them before. The other as `"cat","dist"`, I don't know what are because in the tools box have these names but maybe I have to put these name on other way.

```
nom_resultado2 = r'D:\user4\Desktop\project\output2.shp'

parameters = { 'FROM' : layer1,
    'TO' : layer2,
    'UPLOAD' : cat,dist
    'COLUMN' : to_cat, dist
    'OUTPUT' : nom_resultado2
    }
processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:v.distance', parameters)
```

And I have to put maximum distance and minimum distance, but doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that the tool works when you run it manually? Go to Processing Toolbox - History, or press Ctrl+Alt+H, click the line with your command and check syntax there. What do you mean by "doesnt work"

Comment: To get more help on the algorithm and the parameters type `processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:v.distance")` inside the python console. A problem could be that you try to call `qgis:v.distance` instead of `grass7:v.distance`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but that work when I use 2 layers, one layer with points and the other is an offset of lines.
But If I use a merge of 2 layers(2 layers of offset) instead of just one offset of lines. doesn't work